# Async/Await while another method does the action

Tags: c#, async-await

I want to implement a flow in which when calling async methods in my class, they would sign up to a scheduler list and wait. Then another thread running and executing methods from the scheduler list, and when each action is finished, the await will finish and I will return the value that was calculated.

Here is my code so far:

```
private List<Func<ClassA, ClassB, ResponseBase>> _actionsDict;
public ExecutingScheduler()
{
    _actionsDict = new List<Func<ClassA, ClassB, ResponseBase>>();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(ExecuteNextTask);
}

private void ExecuteNextTask()
{
    while (_actionsDict.Count > 0)
    {
        // Get first while removing it
        var next = _actionsDict[0];
        _actionsDict.RemoveAt(0);

        // Next line has an error now, how do I call it with the original params as I added it to the list
        next();

        Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}

public async Task<ResponseBase> StartStreamAsync(ClassA classA, ClassB classB)
{
    _actionsDict.Add((unit, guid) => StartStream(classA, classB));

    // I don't want the first each time, I want to await the same instance as I added
    var response = await Task.Run(() => _actionsDict[0](classA, classB)); 
    return response;
}

public async Task<ResponseBase> PrepareStreamAsync(ClassA classA, ClassB classB)
{
    _actionsDict.Add((unit, guid) => PrepareStream(classA, classB));

    // I don't want the first each time, I want to await the same instance as I added
    var response = await Task.Run(() => _actionsDict[0](classA, classB)); 
    return response;
}
```

So two questions:
1) How do I properly add to the list of actions so I can later call functions from the list one after one with their params?

2) How do I properly pass the return value from that executer method to the caller of the original request?

feel free to suggest a different approach

Comment: Have you looked into [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh228603 "Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)")?

Comment: @AlexD: You're asking for an incredibly complex solution, which begs me to ask: why do you need this? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @StephenCleary I think he want to queue up a bunch of pseudo-`Task`s and then run them asynchronously, then `await` `WhenAll` complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get your question. But I assume that you need a class with two `async` methods that would do things as the order in the `actionDict`.

Anyway, here's the code: **(New Version)**

```
    List<Task<ResponseBase>> _actionsDict = new List<Task<ResponseBase>>();
    Timer _timer = new Timer(1000);

    public ExecutingScheduler()
    {
        _timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
            while (_actionsDict.Count > 0) {
                var a = _actionsDict[0];
                _actionsDict.RemoveAt(0);

                a.Start();
                a.Wait();
            }
        };
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public Task<ResponseBase> StartStreamAsync(ClassA classA, ClassB classB)
    {
        return QueueResponse(() => StartStream(classA, classB));
    }

    public Task<ResponseBase> PrepareStreamAsync(ClassA classA, ClassB classB)
    {
        return QueueResponse(() => PrepareStream(classA, classB));
    }

    public Task<ResponseBase> QueueResponse(Func<ResponseBase> action)
    {
        var t = new Task<ResponseBase>(action);
        _actionsDict.Add(t);

        return Task.Run(() => t.Result);
    }
```

Comment: What the heck is `return Task.Run(() => task.Result)`?! Don't you mean `return task.ConfigureAwait(false)`?

Comment: @Aron Certainly not, user may call `await StartStreamAsync` means that the method should return a task, yet the `ConfigureAwait(false)` would return a `ConfigurableAwaiter`, which would not compile. The reason to wrap the `t.Result` with a `Task` is that when user awaits this task to run, it will block them (cause the task has not been executed). The `timer` works every 1s to make sure all the queued tasks would run properly. After each task ran, the `t.Result` would be available and would be return from that task. User then could do things impending.

Answer (score -1):

**(EDITED)**
Instead of adding functions to actions collection you could add task to collection.

```
//Better use thread-safe ConcurrentQueue
private ConcurrentQueue<Task<ResponseBase>> _actions;

public ExecutingScheduler()
{
    _actions = new ConcurrentQueue<Task<ResponseBase>>();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(ExecuteNextTask);
}

private void ExecuteNextTask()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Get first while removing it
        Task<ResponseBase> next;
        var containsElement = _actions.TryDequeue(out next);
        if (containsElement)
        {
            next.Start();
            next.Wait();
        }
        Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}

public async Task<ResponseBase> StartStreamAsync(ClassA classA, ClassB classB)
{
    var task = new Task<ResponseBase>(() => StartStream(classA, classB));

    //Add task to queue
    _actions.Enqueue(task);

    var result = await task;

    return result;
}

public async Task<ResponseBase> PrepareStreamAsync(ClassA classA, ClassB classB)
{
    var task = new Task<ResponseBase>(() => PrepareStream(classA, classB));

    //Add task to queue
    _actions.Enqueue(task);

    var result = await task;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How about explaining you code a little bit? What does it differently/correctly from OP's code?

Comment: This does not run. And definitely does not work asynchronously.

Comment: @CliveDM I think it will run asynchronously, but it will just deadlock, that's all. #NeverUseTaskResult

Comment: @Aron with his original post, he did not `await` for the task to run, so it'll run synchronously. And the `ExecuteNextTask` method (now fixed) would run only once when the class has been constructed, at that time the `_actionsDict.Count > 0` would be false and the whole method would return immediately, with no recalling for that method, all the tasks would queued in the list without being executing. Therefore the `task.Result` would never be obtained which would cause the whole thread dead.

Comment: @NikitaIlin Yep, that seems to run. One problem, once the whole queue ran out, this `while(true)` would consume a massive amount of CPU time (I mean all), consider use a `Timer` instead.

Comment: @CliveDM thanks for comments! 'while(true)' will not consume a massive amount of CPU time because of Task.Delay. But using 'true' inside 'while' isn't really good practice and suggested timer will be much better. Another solution is to create '_running' variable and use 'while(_running)'

Comment: @NikitaIlin Good choice.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to reimplement the Task Parallel Library. Specifically `TaskScheduler` and `Task.WhenAll`.

Try this instead.

```
var queries = new [] 
              { 
                  new { ClassA =..., ClassB = ...},
                  new { ClassA =..., ClassB = ...},
                  new { ClassA =..., ClassB = ...},
              };
var tasks = queries.Select(item => Task.Run(() => PrepareStream(item.ClassA, item.ClassB);
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

However with a name like `PrepareStream` I suspect you REALLY DON'T WANT TO USE A THREAD.

Threading should ONLY BE USED when you are CPU bound or you have a special (UI) thread (which is a special case of CPU bound).

Comment: OP said that `they (the ones called the asynchronous method) would sign up to a scheduler list and wait`, and according to his original code, he means that the `ExecutingScheduler` class holds a list of the async method calls, and perform them one by one, not all together.